# Can someone help to differentiate this function $1/x^x$?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

My teacher let me investigate how to differentiate $${1\over x^x}$$ but I don't really know how to do it. 
**I tried** 
$$x^n = nx^{n-1}$$
and **L'Hopital's** rule but that did not work or maybe I didn't do correctly. If someone could help me I would be really grateful :D

Comment: l'Hopital's rule is not appropriate for derivatives.  Do you know the formula for the derivative of $x^x$?  Remember that $x^x=e^{x\ln x}$.

Comment: let $y=x^{-x}$. Take logarithms $ \ln y = -x \ln x $. Differentiate $ \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx}= -(1+\ln x)$. Now multiply by $y$ and substitute back in for $y$.

Answer (score 6):

You have to consider that :

$$\frac1{x^x}=e^{-x\ln(x)}$$

This allows to compute the derivative :

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac1{x^x}\right)=-\left(1+\ln(x)\right)e^{-x\ln(x)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the function as $y=x^{-x}$ the best way to do this to make sure you don't forget your chain rule is to use logarithmic differentiation. $\ln y=-x\ln x\to \frac{y\prime}{y}=-\ln x-1\to y\prime(-\ln x-1)=-x^{-x}(\ln x+1)$

Answer (score 2):

Note that:
$$x^x=e^{x\ln{x}}$$
Hence, you must differentiate:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{x^x}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x\ln{x}})$$
Now, you can use a combination of the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) and [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

---

> and **L'Hopital's** rule but that did not work or maybe I didn't do correctly

Note that you cannot use [L'Hopital's rule](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LHospitalsRule.aspx) to evaluate derivatives. However, it is useful when evaluating certain limits. For derivatives, something similar would be the [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule), however note that you'd have evaluate the derivative of $x^x$ first.

---

> **I tried** $x^n=nx^{n-1}$

Also, note that you cannot use the [power rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule) in this case:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$$
Since that only works if $n$ is a real valued **constant**. In this case, we are varying $x$, thus we cannot use it.

Answer (score 2):

By the multivariable chain rule:

Let $y=u^v$, $u=x$, and $v=-x$.  Then

$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dx}\\&=vu^{v-1}-\ln(u)u^v\\&=-(1+\ln(x))x^{-x}\end{align}$$

Comment: do you need a minus sign on the first term ?

Comment: Sure $ \frac{ \partial y}{ \partial u} =vu^{v-1}$ ... I make that $-x^{-x}$ when you subtitute back in ?

Comment: Ah, right... I missed that.  Thanks!